# Django-endless-pagination fails when using template inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pagination

[Django Endless Pagination](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/) works perfectly fine right until I use template inheritance.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    objects = range(30)

    return render(request,
        'index.html',
        locals()
    )
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "root.html" %}

{% load endless %}

{% paginate objects %}
{% block content %}
    {{ objects }}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    {% show_pages %}
{% endblock %}
```

root.html:

```
<div class="content">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

If I uncomment the line `{% extends "root.html" %}` in index.html it works. Otherwise I get the following error:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /Users/tuk/Desktop/endlesstest/templates/index.html, error at line 10
Cannot find endless page in context.

1   {% extends "root.html" %}
2   
3   {% load endless %}
4   
5   {% paginate objects %}
6   {% block content %}
7       {{ objects }}
8       <br/>
9       <br/>
10      {% show_pages %}
11  {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line only execute when this template is into a block or this template does not extends to other

`{% load endless %}`

Do you install the app in your settings?

Comment: Great, that was it, thank you so much! I moved the `load endless` and `paginate objects` tags to the block and it works.

Comment: Oh, actually only `{% paginate objects %}` needs to be in the block.

Comment: Yes, everything that is out of a block is like this thing not was in the template file, when this extends to other template